# CSS percentage width is not working

Tags: html, css, width, percentage

I am getting a weird problem while using CSS width property.

```
 <form action="#form2"  method="post" id="form1" name="form1">
  <ul id="flx-skill" style="display:inline;">                               
                     <li class="clearfix"><p class="span4" style="font-size:17px; color:black; text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px grey;"><b>1. Personal </b></p><p class="span4">2.  Medical</p><p class="span4">3. Lifestyle</p><p class="span4">4. Diet</p>
                                    <div class="progress-bar green animate" style="width:100%;">
                                        <span class="progress-60" style="width: 25%">
                                                <span></span>
```

This seems to work with width as 25%. But for another form when I'm entering width as 50%. It's not working and instead it is taking as 50px.

```
<ul id="flx-skill" style="display:inline;">                             
                     <li class="clearfix"><p class="span4" style="font-size:17px; color:black; text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px grey;"><b>1. Personal </b></p><p class="span4">2.  Medical</p><p class="span4">3. Lifestyle</p><p class="span4">4. Diet</p>
                                    <div class="progress-bar green animate" style="width:100%;">
                                        <span class="progress-60" style="width: 50%;">
                                            <span></span>
```

Kindly let me know where I'm going wrong. Here's the [link](http://www.nurturehealthsolutions.com/hra.aspx)

Comment: When I scroll down, the form dances :P Is that normal behavior?

Comment: could you please it more detail with image so it help us to easy understanding

Comment: percentage widths looks to be working fine when I tried

Comment: Hi, you don't nee to go till the last. Just check out the second form. There if you can see in vew source I have written width to be 50% but if you inspect elemnt, it is coming out to be 50 px

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be a percentage of something unspecified. 10% of 0 is equal 0. So in that way 10% of 1000px = 100px. If you write the height in pixels you are attributing a size.

You might need as well to make the positions `relative`, then `width:100%` and `width: 50%;` should work:

## Your First Example

```
<form action="#form2"  method="post" id="form1" name="form1">
  <ul id="flx-skill" style="display:inline;">                               
                     <li class="clearfix"><p class="span4" style="font-size:17px; color:black; text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px grey;"><b>1. Personal </b></p><p class="span4">2.  Medical</p><p class="span4">3. Lifestyle</p><p class="span4">4. Diet</p>
                                    <div class="progress-bar green animate" style="width:100%; position: relative">
                                        <span class="progress-60" style="width: 25%; position: relative">
                                                <span></span>
```

## Second Example

```
<ul id="flx-skill" style="display:inline;">                             
                     <li class="clearfix"><p class="span4" style="font-size:17px; color:black; text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px grey;"><b>1. Personal </b></p><p class="span4">2.  Medical</p><p class="span4">3. Lifestyle</p><p class="span4">4. Diet</p>
                                    <div class="progress-bar green animate" style="width:100%; position: relative">
                                        <span class="progress-60" **style="width: 50%;** position: relative">
                                            <span></span>
```

Do not forget to remove the syntax errors where you have `width: 50%;`.

Comment: Hi, width: 50%;** was a typo or formatting error on my part. However i tried with position : relative. Its not working